# JSF Primefaces can't reenable radiobutton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following very simple page containg two selectoneradio groups using PF 5, netbeans and glassfish. I have checked in several browsers and the results are the same.

The first controls the other. When i change choice1 i can see the buttons in choice2 being disabled and enabled as I'd expect.

When the page is 'fresh' i can toggle the values in choice2. But first time i change a value in choice1 causing choice2 to change...it remains inaccessible.

Can anyone explain to my why? I think i read about a checkbox having the same problem and it was because what you see isn't the control but just an image. But I can't find that information again.

The code:

My page:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form id="prodForm">
        <p:selectOneRadio id="choice1"  value="#{myBean.firstChoice}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 choice" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1 choice" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2 choice" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3 choice" itemValue="3" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="4 choice" itemValue="4" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="5 choice" itemValue="5" />
            <p:ajax  update="choice2 ch2Id0 ch2Id1 ch2Id2 ch2Id3" listener="#{myBean.doSomething()}" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <h3>Choice 2</h3>
        <p:selectOneRadio id="choice2" value="#{myBean.secondChoice}" layout="custom" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 0" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 1" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 2" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 3" itemValue="3" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <p:radioButton id="ch2Id0" for="choice2" itemIndex="0" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 1}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="ch2Id1" value="Choice 2 0" /><br/>
        <p:radioButton id="ch2Id1" for="choice2" itemIndex="1" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 3}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="ch2Id1" value="Choice 2 1" /><br/>
        <p:radioButton id="ch2Id2" for="choice2" itemIndex="2" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 4}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="ch2Id1" value="Choice 2 2" /><br/>
        <p:radioButton id="ch2Id3" for="choice2" itemIndex="3" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 5}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="ch2Id1" value="Choice 2 3" /><br/>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

and my bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
Integer firstChoice = 5;
Integer secondChoice = 0;

public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("In doSomething");
}


public Integer getFirstChoice() {
    return firstChoice;
}
public void setFirstChoice(Integer firstChoice) {
    this.firstChoice = firstChoice;
}
public Integer getSecondChoice() {
    return secondChoice;
}
public void setSecondChoice(Integer secondChoice) {
    this.secondChoice = secondChoice;
}
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Kim

Comment: Use `<h:body>` instead of just `<body>`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry but indeed i can't figure out what is your problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution `<p:ajax  update="@form" listener="#{myBean.doSomething()}" />`.

Or if you dont want to update the form, you can wrap the `<p:selectOneRadio>` and the group of `<p:radioButton>` inside a `<p:outputPanel>`, then just update that panel.

Like this :

```
<h:form id="prodForm" prependId="false">
        <p:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{myBean.doSomething()}" id="choice1"  value="#{myBean.firstChoice}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="0 choice" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1 choice" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2 choice" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="3 choice" itemValue="3" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="4 choice" itemValue="4" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="5 choice" itemValue="5" />
            <p:ajax   update="choice2panel"  />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <h3>Choice 2</h3>
        <p:outputPanel  id="choice2panel">
        <p:selectOneRadio immediate="true" id="choice2" value="#{myBean.secondChoice}" layout="custom" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 0" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 1" itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 2" itemValue="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choice 2 3" itemValue="3" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
        <p:radioButton  id="ch2Id0" for="choice2" itemIndex="0" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 1}" />
        <h:outputLabel id="l0" for="ch2Id0" value="Choice 2 0" /><br/>
        <p:radioButton  id="ch2Id1" for="choice2" itemIndex="1" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 3}" />
        <h:outputLabel id="l1" for="ch2Id1" value="Choice 2 1" /><br/>
        <p:radioButton id="ch2Id2" for="choice2" itemIndex="2" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 4}" />
        <h:outputLabel id="l2" for="ch2Id2" value="Choice 2 2" /><br/>
        <p:radioButton id="ch2Id3" for="choice2" itemIndex="3" disabled="#{myBean.firstChoice lt 5}" />
        <h:outputLabel id="l3" for="ch2Id3" value="Choice 2 3" /><br/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT, that little detail seems to have solved my problem.